# generating HTML dynamically when quotes are involved

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script:

```
function Start() {

    var TheData = 'tes"sst3\'k';

    var TheHTML = '<div class="SomeClass">' + TheData + '</div>';
    TheHTML += '<input type="text" id="TheTextBox" value="';
    TheHTML += TheData + '" />';

    $('#Dynamic').html(TheHTML);
}
```

Basically, I'm creating HTML on the fly and embedding some variable text into it. The problem is that the text contains quotes and the value of the textbox doesn't match the value of the label because of the quotes. How can I solve this??

[image]

The jsFiddle is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Sj7K/).

Thanks

Comment: You need to escape your text.

Comment: The issue is that the `value` in your textbox uses double quotes, so the double quote in `TheData` is ending the value after `tes`

Comment: To escape a quote inside an attribute, use `&quot;`. but you don't need to escape it if you use methods to set the value rather than string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, instead of worrying about escaping the string, just do this:

```
$(Start);
function Start() {
    var TheData = 'tes"sst3\'k';
    var TheHTML = '<div class="SomeClass">' + TheData + '</div>';
    TheHTML += '<input type="text" id="TheTextBox" />';
    $('#Dynamic').html(TheHTML);
    $('#TheTextBox').val(TheData);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6Sj7K/5/)**

Comment: Ok, thanks; I figured that this would be the only way to do it; first generate blank HTML, add it to the DOM, and then fill in the values.

Comment: I have follow-up jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wWEC8/2/ Does this solve the problem or is there an edge case I didn't think of?

Answer (score 3):

It's much safer (for this exact reason) to let jQuery worry about all that and generate your `HTML` like this:

```
var $input = $("<input>").attr("id","TheTextBox").val(TheData);
var $div = $("<div>").addClass("SomeClass").text(TheData).append($input);

var $wrapper = $("<div>").append($div);
var TheHTML = $wrapper.html();
```

Comment: FYI, you can also use this form to create the element with attributes and values: `$("<input>", {id: "TheTextBox", val: TheData});` I believe. Also I don't see a reason for the `$wrapper.html()` in the end. Just do `$('#Dynamic').empty().append($div)`.

Comment: I have follow-up jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wWEC8/2/ Does this solve the problem or is there an edge case I didn't think of?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the quotes, like this:

```
var TheData = 'tes&quot;sst3&apos;k';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```
$(Start);

function Start() {

    var TheData = 'tes"sst3\'k';

    var TheHTML = '<div class="SomeClass">' + TheData + '</div>';
    TheHTML += '<input type="text" id="TheTextBox" value=';
    TheHTML += TheData + ' />';

    $('#Dynamic').html(TheHTML);
}
```